# Simple SQL query taking a long time

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I use to determine what the interval is between timestamps of gauge data using the 2 most recent readings:

```
 $interval_query    = sprintf("SELECT `stamp` 
                              FROM `processed_gauge_data`
                              WHERE `processed_gauge_data`.`gauge_id` IN (%s) 
                              ORDER BY `processed_gauge_data`.`stamp` DESC LIMIT 2;",
                      $gauge_id
                  );
```

Here is an image with EXPLAIN results as well as the structure of the table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaDRP.png

This has worked fine for most gauges, but there are 2 in particular that it takes 30-45 seconds to execute this query. Selecting all data for those 2 gauges takes less than a second. What is causing this? I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: What is the exact query? (the value of $interval_query) What is the schema of data_table?

Comment: Have you tried using Explain for your query?

Comment: do you have index on `data_table.gauge_id` an d on `data_table.stamp`?

Comment: explain plan is the first thing you should be looking at in such cases. Before even thinking about posting to stackoverflow

Comment: I have added an image containing EXPLAIN results and table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because of **ORDER BY `processed_gauge_data`.`stamp` DESC**.  I changed my query to ORDER BY 'id' and it went from 30-45 seconds to .0006-.0003 seconds:

```
 $interval_query    = sprintf("SELECT `stamp`, 'id' 
                          FROM `processed_gauge_data`
                          WHERE `processed_gauge_data`.`gauge_id` IN (%s) 
                          ORDER BY `processed_gauge_data`.`id` DESC LIMIT 2;",
                  $gauge_id
              );
```